# Can EKS Autoscaling parameters (min, max, desired nodes) be changed without having to restart the EKS Cluster?

Tags: amazon-eks

For Amazon EKS cluster - Is it possible to change the autoscale vitals (min, max, desired nodes) without having to restart the cluster? If yes, is there an API for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change of auto scaling group parameters does not restart the EKS cluster. Example you can change by visit the console EC2 > Auto Scaling groups > Click on your cluster group. Edit the "Desired capacity", "Minimum capacity" and "Maximum capacity" on the "Details" tab. Once you click "Update" the change will be carry out WITHOUT restart of EKS cluster. The same thing can also be perform by using aws ec2 cli.